# Very high RAM usage in Ubuntu 20.04 on startup

Tags: ram, zfs, htop

When I start my computer, the `htop` command shows a very high RAM usage, even without having started the web browser, which is a very common resource eater. Is this normal? Can I do something to reduce this enormous RAM consumption.

[image: Htop as normal user]

If you need more information or logs I am grateful to provide them.

Htop as root user, after rebooting the computer.
[image: Htop as root user]

The system was installed using ZFS in Ubuntu

Comment: @HoltJackson How do you know? What program it could be? How to detect it?

Comment: @Jackson I think saying it's malware is jumping to conclusions.....

Comment: Can you run `htop` as superuser (`sudo htop`) and see if it shows more processes than in your original screenshot? In the original screenshot it doesn't seem that the process eating all the memory is listed

Comment: @You'reAGitForNotUsingGit I just see the same proceses but with a lot of threads each one. I've updated the screenshots in the question.

Comment: I was thinking ZFS, it would be worthwhile to know what the system was installed with? ZFS or non Ext4. if we can get that it would be great

Comment: @RajatPandita Yeah, Ubuntu was installed with ZFS. What is that memory used for? It can be reduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a duplicate of [Is ZFS on Ubuntu 20.04 using a ton of memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230150/is-zfs-on-ubuntu-20-04-using-a-ton-of-memory)
Please go through this thread and you will have more information. In short you can't do it, this is used for caching you can reduce it to some extent but not entirely.